# Boto interfacing to Amazon Mechanical turk - Hit creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk, crowdsourcing

I'm new to amazon and python, so forgive me this is a easy fix. Upon creating a hit from boto I get the following error:

```
boto.mturk.connection.MTurkRequestError: MTurkRequestError: 200 OK

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetAssignmentsForHITResponse><OperationRequest><RequestId>17449b9f-b1f3-4d54-bbbd-974210ce1c1b</RequestId><Errors><Error><Code>AWS.BadClaimsSupplied</Code><Message>The specified claims are invalid.   Based on your request, your signature should be generated using the following string: ActionGetAssignmentsForHITAWSAccessKeyId*********HITId?PageNumber1PageSize10SignatureVersion1SortDirectionAscendingSortPropertySubmitTimeTimestamp2014-01-06T22:20:05ZVersion2012-03-25.  Check to make sure your system clock and timezone is not incorrect.  Our current system time: 2014-01-06T22:20:05Z.  (1389046806029 s)</Message><Data><Key>CustomerSignature</Key><Value>**************=</Value></Data><Data><Key>StringToSign</Key><Value>ActionGetAssignmentsForHITAWSAccessKeyIdAKIAIYFUA5FGNQKNWUSQHITId?PageNumber1PageSize10SignatureVersion1SortDirectionAscendingSortPropertySubmitTimeTimestamp2014-01-06T22:20:05ZVersion2012-03-25</Value></Data><Data><Key>SystemTime</Key><Value>2014-01-06T22:20:05Z</Value></Data></Error></Errors></OperationRequest></GetAssignmentsForHITResponse>
```

From my understanding the problem is an inconsistency between my system's clock and the amazon system clock. I've tried synchronizing the clock right before i create a hit but the error persists.

Notes:
this time the times match perfectly but there has been instances where they were 1 to 3 seconds apart! if it helps at all, this is part of implementing crowdforge that Im having trouble with.

Comment: Can you provide the code that generated this error?

Comment: I was using Django and generated hits in the interface, so there is no code besides the standard libraries. I reverted back to version 1.8d from the latest version and the error went away. I guess the newer versions are not compatible crowdforge. thanks anyways!

Comment: What version of boto fixed it?